# How do I install "Reentrant POSIX REGEX software"?

Tags: apt, openldap

I'm in the process of installing OpenLDAP, and the README file states that "Reentrant POSIX REGEX software" is required. Is there a package I can install with `apt install` to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would be `libc6-dev`, the development headers for glibc on Ubuntu. The regex functions provided by glibc are reentrant (note how they're marked MT-safe in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#POSIX-Regexp-Compilation)).

That said, since OpenLDAP is in the repositories, why not install slapd from the repositories? See [the Ubuntu LTS Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html) on installing OpenLDAP for more.